# Bitrate missing in mp3 file generated using Cordova Plugin Media

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a cordova app and I am using Cordova plugin Media to record voice in mp3 format, but the file do not have bitrate and length because of which the file does not get played. kindly assist.

Also, please let me know if there is any better audio recorder which works in both Andriod and IOS.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media

```
 // Record audio
//
 function recordAudio() {
var src = "myrecording.mp3";
var mediaRec = new Media(src,
    // success callback
    function() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    // error callback
    function(err) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    }
);

// Record audio
mediaRec.startRecord();

// Stop recording after 10 seconds
```